# Not Able to Parse JSON Data in WebView

Tags: ios, json, uiwebview, string-decoding

i am Newbie in iOS Development.i want to load only "description" Key Data in to UIWebView From my Url Here my Url like as

```
http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/specific_post.php?post_id=2885
```

and i parsed Data For it like as

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self.webSpinner startAnimating];
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/specific_post.php?post_id=2885"]];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata
{
if (responsedata.length > 0)
{
    NSError* error;
    self.webDictionary= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    self.webArray=[_webDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
}
self.webViewString=[self.webArray valueForKey:@"description"];
NSString *descriptionString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.webViewString];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:descriptionString baseURL:nil];
```

then it print Data in WebView Like as

```
"<img style='width: 100% !important; height: auto; margin: 30px 20px 30px 20px;' class=\"alignnone size-full wp-image-2967\" src=\"http://www.janvajevu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Amazing-talented-people-in-the-world.jpg\" alt=\"Amazing talented people in the world\" width=\"0\" height=\"0\" />\U0a9c\U0ac1\U0a93 \U0aa6\U0ac1\U0aa8\U0abf\U0aaf\U0abe \U0aa8\U0abe\U0a85\U0a9c\U0aac \U0a97\U0a9c\U0aac \U0a9f\U0ac7\U0ab2\U0ac7\U0a82\U0a9f\U0ac7\U0aa1 \U0ab2\U0acb\U0a95\U0acb<br />
\n<br />
\nhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo0Cazxj_yc"
```

And When i Encoded Them like as

```
NSData *webViewDatastring = [descriptionString dataUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
NSString *webUnicodeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webViewDatastring encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *webViewString=[webUnicodeString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToTrim];
```

and Load them in to WebView like as

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:webViewString baseURL:nil];
```

then it Return Null. So I confuse about that how to encode This HTML Data then it is Shown in to UIWebView please Give me Solution For that else Give me Resource for this type of tutorial.

Comment: What encoding you are using on server side?

Comment: and try to send your tag content in <![CDATA[]] tag

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman utf8 using in Server Side. and when i use `NSString *webUnicodeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webViewDatastring encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` then it show Same as Above.

Comment: Use `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` in `NSJSONSerialization` instead of `kNilOptions`.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman how to use tag <![CDATA[]]? please tell me About it or give me any resource material for that.

Comment: And too you don't need to decode the HTML on your own, your FONT will do this, just use as it is..

Comment: @iphonic it is Not working i used it and try it it shows same Data in decoded form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am simply doing the following process its working for me directly.

```
NSData *jsonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/specific_post.php?post_id=2885"]];
NSJSONSerialization *jsonParser=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

NSDictionary *data=[[(NSDictionary *)jsonParser objectForKey:@"data"] lastObject];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:[data objectForKey:@"description"] baseURL:nil];
```

See output

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes it is Working but it is not Shows Youtube Url like as HTTP URL in Webview Please Give me Solution for it.Because some View Contain Youtube Url and i want it clicable.

Comment: If there is any url in the html it will work automatically, if you click on it, it will open youtube page automatically.

Comment: Sorry Bro it is Working i not set my UIWebView to Detection of Link I got it Finally.